# How to implement Biometric Fingerprint based Authentication in a ReactJS Web Application With Nodejs backend powered by MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am currently working on a web application set up using ReactJS/Electron for the front-end, Nodejs for the back-end and MongoDB for the database. I want to implement a Fingerprint based authentication-attendance System using external USB scanner which when plugged in to the computer; it will be used for user authentication on the login page of the web application (using ReactJS).

How can this be implemented, is there any NPM package I should be using or any other webAPI that can help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great NPM package for an OpenSaaS biometric authentication provider: https://www.npmjs.com/org/loginid

You can read the documentation here: https://docs.loginid.io/Server-SDKs/Node/node-get-started